# SaxonJS - xslt3 - ObjectNotFound: (xslt3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

Tags: saxon, saxon-js

I would like to transform XML File with Stylesheet XSLT with Saxon JS.

I did:
npm install saxon-js
npm install xslt3

Next Step is: xslt3 -xsl:xslt_filepath.xslt -export:books.sef.json -nogo

I am getting error

```
xslt3 : Die Benennung "xslt3" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise 
des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ xslt3
+
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (xslt3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

packet.json has

```
"xslt3": "^2.0.2",
"saxon-js": "^2.0.2",
```

what could be a problem?

i have same error on my Windows 10 PC, and on windows 10 Laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing with the `-g` (global) option on the `npm` command.